# Have I correctly explained why ¬[¬Q∨(¬P ∧ Q)] is logically equivalent to P∧Q?

Tags: logic, proof-verification

Can somebody check out my reasoning and let me know, if I have gone wrong and why?

Here is the problem:

Use the equivalency laws to find simpler formulas equivalent to these formulas. Explain the reasoning that you used to find your solution:

¬[ ¬Q ∨ (¬P ∧ Q) ]

¬[ ¬Q ∨ (¬P ∧ Q) ] by DeMorgan’s Law, is equivalent to ~~Q and ~(~P and Q).
~~Q is equivalent to Q. 
~(~P and Q), by DeMorgan’s Law, is equivalent to P or ~Q. 
As a whole, the new simplified statement would read Q and (P or Q). Q is redundant. 
Hence, we have P and Q.

Comment: Up to the typo in your third last sentence "Q and (P or Q)" should mean "Q and (P or ~Q)" this looks correct.

Comment: Please give your posts more informative titles and add the proof-verification tag when you're looking for your proposed solution to be evaluated.

Comment: Your last line is incorrect: $Q \land (P \lor Q)$ is not equivalent to $Q \land P$ because the "Q is redundant". It is actually equivalent to $Q$. You made a mistake in your working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you could write out the truth tables for both and show they are the same. It kind of depends on how logically rigorous you need to be. Have you "proven" De-Morgan's laws?

Your proof seems fine (some slight error). Here it is written up neatly:

$$
\begin{align}
\lnot (\lnot Q \lor (\lnot P \land Q)) &\iff \lnot \lnot Q \land \lnot (\lnot P \land Q) \\
&\iff Q \land (\lnot\lnot P \lor  \lnot Q) \\
&\iff Q \land (P \lor  \lnot Q) \\
&\iff (Q \land P) \lor  (Q \land \lnot Q) \\
&\iff (Q \land P) \lor  \bot \\
&\iff Q \land P 
\end{align}
$$